# create a new spark DataFrame column without using ID

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame about connection log with columns `targetIP`, `Time`. Every record in this DataFrame is a connection event to one system.  `targetIP` means the target IP address this time, Time is the connection time. With Values:

| Time | targetIP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 2 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 3 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 5 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 6 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 7 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 8 | 192.163.0.2 |

I want to create a new column under some condition: count of connections to this time's target IP address in the past 3 connections. So the result DataFrame should be:

| Time | targetIP | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192.163.0.1 | 0 |
| 2 | 192.163.0.2 | 0 |
| 3 | 192.163.0.1 | 1 |
| 5 | 192.163.0.1 | 2 |
| 6 | 192.163.0.2 | 1 |
| 7 | 192.163.0.2 | 1 |
| 8 | 192.163.0.2 | 2 |

For example, `Time=8`, the `targetIP` is `192.163.0.2`, connected to system in the past 3 connections, which are `Time=5` `Time=6` and `Time=7`. `Time=6` and `Time=7`'s `targetIP` are also `192.163.0.2`. So the count about `Time=8` is 2.

I have an idea that add a new `ID` column to this DataFrame:

| ID | Time | targetIP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 3 | 3 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 4 | 5 | 192.163.0.1 |
| 5 | 6 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 6 | 7 | 192.163.0.2 |
| 7 | 8 | 192.163.0.2 |

and using Window function:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("targetIP").orderBy(F.col("ID").cast("int")).rangeBetween(-3,-1)
df1= df.withColumn("count", F.count("*").over(w)).orderBy("ID")
```

but if I use `monotonically_increasing_id()`, the ID is not sequential. So I want to get your help without using ID.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to assign an ID:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'id',
    F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('Time'))
).withColumn(
    'count', 
    F.count('*').over(
        Window.partitionBy('targetIP').orderBy('id').rangeBetween(-3,-1)
    )
).orderBy('Time')

df2.show()
+----+-----------+---+-----+
|Time|   targetIP| id|count|
+----+-----------+---+-----+
|   1|192.163.0.1|  1|    0|
|   2|192.163.0.2|  2|    0|
|   3|192.163.0.1|  3|    1|
|   5|192.163.0.1|  4|    2|
|   6|192.163.0.2|  5|    1|
|   7|192.163.0.2|  6|    1|
|   8|192.163.0.2|  7|    2|
+----+-----------+---+-----+
```

Another way without using ID is to do a `collect_list` and filter the resulting array:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'count',
    F.expr("""
        size(filter(
            collect_list(targetIP) over (order by Time rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding),
            x -> x = targetIP
        ))
    """)
)

df2.show()
+----+-----------+-----+
|Time|   targetIP|count|
+----+-----------+-----+
|   1|192.163.0.1|    0|
|   2|192.163.0.2|    0|
|   3|192.163.0.1|    1|
|   5|192.163.0.1|    2|
|   6|192.163.0.2|    1|
|   7|192.163.0.2|    1|
|   8|192.163.0.2|    2|
+----+-----------+-----+
```